# Laravel Intervention/ Image Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, image, laravel, memory-management, upload

I have a photography website I am working on in Laravel. I utilize a package called Intervention / Image. In the sites administrative area is a place where admins can create projects then upload any number of images to that project. The problem is that if the images are sizable 4mb or bigger and there are 10 or more being uploaded at one time I get this error:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

I feel like the script or library is using to much memory but I'm not sure what is wrong. I know I can bump up the memory and time limit but I don't feel like I should need to.

I also tried smaller images 100kb or less, any number of images over 20 kills the process and only completes the first 20 images. I checked the server and the images are being properly uploaded to the correct location but it's not writing to the database.

I'm not sure which is causing the problem the upload or the querys. Below is the controller that uploads the images. As a side note the script is also creating four file sizes as well of each image.

```
<?php

class UploadController extends BaseController {

    private $sizes = array( 'large' => 2000, 'medium' => 1500, 'small' => 1000, 'thumb' => 300 );

    public function upload( $id ) {

        $movedArray = array();
        $errors = 0;

        $images = Input::file('images');

        foreach( $images as $img ) {

            $oName = $img->getClientOriginalName();
            $oMimeType = $img->getMimeType();
            $oSize = $img->getSize();
            $oExt = $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $oTemp = $img->getRealPath();

            // get original file name
            $name = str_replace( array(' '), array('-'), $oName );

            $orig = $oTemp;

            $image_original = Image::make( $img );

            foreach( $this -> sizes as $sizename => $size ) {

                $movedPath = public_path() .'/projects/';
                $movedName = strtotime('now') .'-'. $id .'-'. $sizename .'-'. $name;

                $moved = $image_original -> resize( $size, null, function( $constraint ) {

                    $constraint -> aspectRatio();

                });

                $resizedMoved = $moved -> save( $movedPath . $movedName );

                $movedArray[$sizename] = $movedName;

            }

            // create the record in the database
            $upload = new Upload;

            $upload -> user_id = Auth::id();
            $upload -> project_id = $id;

            $upload -> thumbnail = $movedArray['thumb'];
            $upload -> small = $movedArray['small'];
            $upload -> medium = $movedArray['medium'];
            $upload -> large = $movedArray['large'];

            $upload -> file_type = $oMimeType;
            $upload -> file_size = $oSize;
            $upload -> file_extension = $oExt;

            $upload -> save();

        }

        if( $errors > 0 ) {
            Session::put('alert-class', 'success');
            Session::put('msg', 'All files have been uploaded');
        } else {
            Session::put('alert-class', 'danger');
            Session::put('msg', 'Uh oh, something went wrong please try again');
        }

        return Redirect::back();

    }
}
```

Is my only option to turn the memory and time limit up? If so, I feel like that is bad programming, because I already set this to:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","1000M");
set_time_limit(1000);
```

And I still get the same error, any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: @DamianMąsior Jesus, thats probably what it is, I looked at the max_file_uploads and its set to 20 and max_input_vars 2500. If you put that as an answer I will mark it correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error your having has nothing to do with memory limit but with time limit and your having this issue due to many manipulation on images and also the upload it self take some time.
Please mention where did you set the set_time_limit(1000) part.

Also you could improve some performence by instead of having an insert query for every image store the data in an array and after completing all the uploads put them all together in 1 insert query.

Comment: I actually put the set_time_limit() directly into the UploadController. I like that part, of storing the images data into an array and then making a single query!

Comment: you can try edit it via php.ini - `max_execution_time` notice that this is only effect php execution time and you might need to edit your `apache/nginx/whatever_web_server_your_using` max execution time as well.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately I don't have access to any of those things since its shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
max_file_uploads
```

in your php.ini :)

Comment: Did you restarted apache or other server after change?

Comment: No I'm not sure how to do that I am on Godaddy shared hosting